# How can I make a link inside a div fill the entire space inside the div?

Tags: css

I have a `div` that has a set width and it is wrapped around a link. I want the link inside to fill the entire space of the `div` so that when I click anywhere inside the `div` (which I have styled to look like a button) it goes to the link. This is what I have tried, but `.link_class` doesn't do what I want. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="button_class">
    <a class="link_class" href="http://www.my_link.com>My Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button_class {
    width:150px;
    padding:5px 7px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.link_class {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: you can use `display:block` in your `.link_class` it will works

Answer (score 89):

This should do the trick:-

By default `a` is an inline element and width does not affect them. So change it to inline-block to have it take the width you specify.

```
.link_class {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HKqe/)

Comment: This helped, but the link only extends out to the padding on the div.

Comment: Yes what do you expect? I mean it extends out to the padding?

Comment: I want it to fill the entire div, not the entire div minus the padding.

Comment: You could try adding negative padding to the <a>

Comment: This is good, but if I give my div a height, the link is stuck at the top. How can I vertically align it to center? paddng-top is rough because the div's height could change.

Comment: This works really fine with `div` elements, but there's a particular case where it doesn't seem to work ; when the link is contained inside a `table` column with `rowspan` (the height 100% is not taken into account). **It seems like having a fixed height wrapper for the link is required to achieve this trick.**

Answer (score 7):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4CsF/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="button_class">
    <a class="link_class" href="http://www.my_link.com">My Link</a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.button_class {
    width:150px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:blue;
}

.link_class {
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px 7px;    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I hope this solution has satisfied your purpose - @Nancy Collier

Comment: I like this, but I don't understand why it works. It this trick that the padding in link_class fills the entire button_class div (assuming it does)?  And the overflow auto makes sure that nothing overflows, ever?

Comment: @codenoob - Its `display:block` that is making it work.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but HTML5 has a better way to do this.

The answer today is:

HTML:

```
<a class="link_class" href="http://www.my_link.com>
   <div class="button_class">My Link</div>
</a>
```

CSS stays the same, except you don't need .link_class anymore.

Comment: This changes the original HTML.

Comment: Yes it does. And it works this way. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Comment: Thank you! This may or may not have been what op was looking for, but it was just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the link a block level element.

```
.link_class {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked. The key was to explicitly set the `div` height and then use `line-height` on the link.

```
.button_class {
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.link_class {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use outer div in first place? Write all your code for the link and show your link as a button. That will simplify your problem.

```
.link_class{width:150px;height:30px;color:#fff;text-align:center;display: block;
           -webkit-border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;
           /*some other styles*/}
```

Check this demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijeetchindhe/TvtRv/7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.button_class {
    display:flex;
}

.link_class {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the bootstrap `class="stretched-link"` in your a element and it will expand to your div.