# How to increase clickable area on div button surrounded by an ahref

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, markup

When I click the sides of this div button, the `ahref` won't activate, not until you actually click on the 'bounding box' for the string `AA`.

[image]

Mark up

```
<a href="#/tags?ticker={{ticker.ticker}}">
    <div class="ticker">{{ticker.ticker}}</div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.ticker {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    clear: both;
    @include rounded(4px);
}
```

It will work if I use a regular AngularJS `ng-click`, however this doesn't need to be a Javascript solution:

```
<div class="ticker" ng-click="tkrs.gotoTicker(ticker.ticker)">
    {{ticker.ticker}}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a similar **Snippet** or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Ah I just figured it out, needed `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a simple attribute: `display: inline-block;` added to `.ticker`

This question below is slightly different from mine, however the same solution works:
[How can I make a link inside a div fill the entire space inside the div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555644/how-can-i-make-a-link-inside-a-div-fill-the-entire-space-inside-the-div)